# Different marker color jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a jQuery range slider in my demo — http://jsfiddle.net/dLWNc/35/

```
$( ".slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: stations.min_value,
      step: stations.step_value,
      max: stations.max_value,
      values: [stations.min_range, stations.max_range],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#min").val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
        $("#max").val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
      }
    });
```

How i filter and set new icon markers dynamically the map look like this:

[image]

Comment: Is that not the third time you post that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iterate over all markers and use setIcon() to set the url of the marker to an image based on the value.

Example:

```
  $.each(station,function(i,v){

    var icon=((v.value < ui.values[0])
                ? 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png'
                : ((v.value > ui.values[1])
                     ? 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
                     : 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png'
               ));
    StationMarkers[i].setIcon(icon);
  });
```

Comment: Efficiency: Create the three URLs once outside the `each` loop, then choose from them inside the loop. Otherwise all three strings are created over and over at every iteration. Lots of needless work for GC.